# How retention policy will interact with retention date change?

Tags: retention

On the OOTB announcement list I added a custom date field "expiredate". Then setup 2 retention stage:

(a) on expire date it trigger workflow A to send notification email

(b) 30 days after expire date it triggher workflow B to send notification email

In case the user have modified the "expiredate" between stage 1 and stage 2 (for instance, modify the expiredate to be a year later) What would happen? Will it reset to stage 0?

Comment: why don't you just test it?

Comment: Yes I will try to test it parallel... but it will take at least 2 days if I didn't make mistake....

Answer (score 1):

As I know and do some tests on retention, the policy is not run the stage (a) after we change the expire date between stage (a) and (b), it will wait to the next stage (b).